# Does anyone know the yFrog RSS feed addresses?

Tags: twitter, rss, yfrog

I want to embed the latest image uploaded to yFrog for a particular user on another site. They appear to have recently launched a widget, and I've found some talk of RSS feeds. But everything relating to them seems to have been pulled from the yFrog site recently. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You should try implementing a Yahoo! Pipe using Twitter and yFrog API to generate an RSS. Here is mine: http://pipes.yahoo.com/norbertcsik/twitter_images

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they used to support, but it doesn't look like it works anymore.

For evidence, see [this](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=%22yfrog.com%2Frss.php%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=f&oq=) and [this](http://getsatisfaction.com/yfrog/topics/new_yfrog_account_empty_rss_feed).